# Where does the energy required for excitation of electrons in hybridization come from?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, hybridization

We're commonly taught that when atoms want to hybridize in for instance methane, an electron is excited from $2s$ to $2p$ to allow for four unpaired electrons, which is necessary for bonding.

Where does the energy for this excitation come from?

Comment: If you are talking about the sp3 hybridization: there is no excitation involved...

Answer (score 3):

*Ab initio* hybridisation is a concept taught in schools to help understand how carbon with its one s- and three p-orbitals can achieve a tetrahedral environment. As part of this process, it is required to *formally* excite an electron.

*Formally* is the key word here. The entire process is a *formal* process that has practically nothing to do with real-life atoms (especially because these real-life atoms rather rarely end up in a vacuum without anything around them as the theory assumes). Thus, in real life this formal energy is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

In this process the energy of s orbital increases, but the energy of three p orbitals decrease.

This is like irl two hungry friends one of them having spam. The one with spam will share it with a friend and (if you look at him alone) his state worsens (say -1). On the other hand his friend benefits (say +2). Sharing still brings the benefit to the system.